# Compartilhar por e-mail um arquivo pdf in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Boa tarde

Tenho um Tab Bar Item e gostaria que quando eu clicasse nele acione uma UIActivityViewController que pagaria um PDF de um link ex:(http://www.meusite/boleto.pdf) e eu possa envia-lo como um anexo de um e-mail.

Comment: o maximo que voce pode fazer é compor uma nova mensagem com o arquivo attached e o usuário envia

Comment: na verdade o arquivo tem que estar no aparelho. Se quiser mandar o link no body do email também pode

Comment: Consegui carregar esse pdf numa webview mas agora não sei como compartilhar num e-mail adicionando esse arquivo, vc teria um código de exemplo?

Comment: @LeoDabus mandar o link no corpo do e-mail eu consegui mas não sei como faz para enviar o arquivo, teria um código de exemplo?

Comment: pra visualizar pdf usa o QuickLook em vez do webview

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller/1616885-addattachmentdata

Comment: ta usando MFMail​Compose​View​Controller?

Comment: se nao conseguir me fala. o mime type pra pdf é `"application/pdf"`

Comment: Estou usando uiactivityindicatorview porém quando ele abre a opção para compor o e-mail o máximo que consigo colocar ali é um link

Comment: @LeoDabus não tem como fazer isso sem usar API, de forma nativa??

Comment: Mais nativo que isso ? Qual o problema de adicionar o import MessageUI?

Comment: @LeoDabus problema nenhum, só queria concluir sem adicionar nenhuma API, tive uns problemas com o Alamofire e fiquei meio reticente em usar

Comment: Essa Framework é da propria Apple

Comment: E é tão velha que suporta iOS 3.0+

Comment: @LeoDabus bom vou tentar com ela então, esse código aí funciona eu já tendo o PDF na view?

Comment: mais fácil ainda é so usar a data do pdf em vez de ler do url arquivo que ta dentro do Bundle

Comment: como assim tem o pdf na view? voce quis dizer webview? Na web view eu nunca tentei. Se voce não postar o seu código fica difícil ajudar

Comment: Explica melhor aonde que ta o pdf que voce quer enviar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce deve usar a MessagesUI api para compor o email pro usuario da seguinte forma:

```
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let mailComposeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mailComposeVC.setToRecipients(["email@address.com"])
        mailComposeVC.setSubject("Assunto !!!")
        mailComposeVC.setMessageBody("Texto da mensagem", isHTML: false) // também pode mandar html

        // para mandar um arquivo
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "nomeDoArquivo", withExtension: "pdf")!) {
            print(data.count)
            mailComposeVC.addAttachmentData(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", fileName: "Any Name")
        }
        present(mailComposeVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Leo meu codigo por enquanto é este

Comment: func asyncTask(parametros: String, id: String) {
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.userInitiated.qosClass).async {`
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let boletoURL = URL(string: "http://www.meusite.com/01_2017.pdf")
                print(boletoURL!)
                let boletoURLRequest = URLRequest(url: boletoURL!)
                self.webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                self.webView.loadRequest(boletoURLRequest)
            }
        }
    }

Comment: voce so precisa baixar o seu pdf antes usando URLSession dataTask(with URL:) . não precisa mostrar na webview.

Comment: Mas a intenção é mostrar na tela, e se o usuario quiser compartilhar para o email dele ou de outra pessoa ter essa opção

Comment: Nao precisa nao quer dizer que voce não pode. Ate melhor voce baixar e exibir o arquivo local.

Comment: O que voce prefere salvar o pdf ou so deixar na memória ? Não tem como salvar o que ta na web view sem ter que render o conteúdo dela e um pdf pode ter varias paginas. Se quiser baixar pra memória tem limite de tamanho. mas como é pra enviar por email 20MB não tem problema

Comment: Eu não consigo pegar esse pdf que esta na webview e anexar num e-mail?

Comment: sim pega a URL e baixa

Comment: É a partir dai que eu não sei mais o que fazer, preciso mudar esse codigo que tenho quando carrego a url na webview?

Comment: por isso que eu disse que é melhor baixar antes de exibir seja na web view ou no QuickLook. QuickLook so exibe local files então como eu disse baixa antes

Comment: Talvez ate tenha como voce pegar o pdf na cache do app mas eu nunca tentei

Comment: vc tem algum codigo que faça tudo isso e já anexe?